# Option string with space causes java error in nltk.parse.stanford parsers

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, stanford-nlp

The following is for NLTK 3.2 paired with stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09 running in Python 2.7.6 (and JDK 8) on Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  First, a little background...

I'd like to keep punctuation in the output from StanfordDependencyParser, so I tried `corenlp_options='-keepPunct'`, which doesn't work.  So I discovered that the way to do this if you were using java on the command line would be with `-outputFormatOptions "includePunctuationDependencies"`.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordDependencyParser as SDP
dp = SDP(corenlp_options='-outputFormatOptions includePunctuationDependencies')
```

But when I try passing that to corenlp_options, it seems ok until I actually try to parse something, then I get an OSError:

```
print [parse.tree() for parse in dp.raw_parse('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.')]

WARNING! lexparser.Options: Unknown option ignored: -outputFormatOptions includePunctuationDependencies
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser - Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz ...
 done [0.4 sec].
Error loading parser, exiting...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown option: -outputFormatOptions includePunctuationDependencies
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Options.setOption(Options.java:175)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Options.setOptions(Options.java:68)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.Options.setOptions(Options.java:49)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.setOptionFlags(LexicalizedParser.java:1007)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:188)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.main(LexicalizedParser.java:1412)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 132, in raw_parse
    return next(self.raw_parse_sents([sentence], verbose))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 150, in raw_parse_sents
    return self._parse_trees_output(self._execute(cmd, '\n'.join(sentences), verbose))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 216, in _execute
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 134, in java
    raise OSError('Java command failed : ' + str(cmd))
OSError: Java command failed : ['/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java', u'-mx1000m', '-cp', '/home/dbl/stanford/stanford-english-corenlp-2016-10-31-models.jar:/home/dbl/stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/stanford-parser-3.6.0-sources.jar:/home/dbl/stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/slf4j-api.jar:/home/dbl/stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/stanford-parser-3.6.0-models.jar:/home/dbl/stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/stanford-parser.jar:/home/dbl/stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/ejml-0.23.jar:/home/dbl/stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/slf4j-simple.jar:/home/dbl/stanford/stanford-parser-full-2015-12-09/stanford-parser-3.6.0-javadoc.jar', u'edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser', u'-model', u'edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz', u'-sentences', u'newline', u'-outputFormat', u'conll2007', u'-encoding', u'utf8', '-outputFormatOptions includePunctuationDependencies', '/tmp/tmpbJ349q']
```

Naturally, if I join that list with space and paste it to a shell prompt, it runs fine.  The problem is that NLTK's java uses Popen, and it's not happy with the space in the corenlp_options.  Other than overriding corenlp_options to extend the cmd list with a split of the string (because appending the string with whitespace is what breaks Popen), do I have any good options?

Here's the relevant snippet from nltk.parse.stanford.GenericStanfordParser (that the dependency parser inherits):

```
def _execute(self, cmd, input_, verbose=False):
    encoding = self._encoding
    cmd.extend(['-encoding', encoding])
    if self.corenlp_options:
        cmd.append(self.corenlp_options)

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the option and the value as separate arguments on the argument list, like all the other options you found. For example: `..., u'-encoding', u'utf8', ...`. So just write `'-outputFormatOptions', 'includePunctuationDependencies'` and you're good to go.

Comment: That would indeed work if I were creating the Popen and cmd list myself (or if I tinkered with the relevant NLTK bits of code), but my question is specifically about how to get this to work within existing NLTK code and the corenlp_options.

Comment: Here's the problem from within the GenericStanfordParser class (`.append(corenlp_options)`, where 
`.extend(self.corenlp_options.split())` would achieve what you suggest): 
`if self.corenlp_options:
    cmd.append(self.corenlp_options)`

Comment: Please edit your question and include the python code you used to inject the option. It's hard to fix code I can't see. That said, you might just need to pass a list instead of a string for `corenlp_options`.

Comment: Done. As I mentioned, I _could_ modify the nltk code, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Filed an issue on nltk's github, and using the workaround of creating a new class that inherits StanfordDependencyParser and fixes the appropriate _execute method.  Would have preferred a simpler workaround, though.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. I don't see a simple solution either. But could you check if you can use `StanfordNeuralDependencyParser` without problems? I'm asking because the class adds a string with a space in it to `corenlp_options`, so I wonder whether that works at all. (Maybe it only works on Windows where executed commands are reparsed from a space-separated string.)

Comment: PS Just in case: You did try the syntax `-outputFormatOptions=includePunctuationDependencies` and it's not supported, right? (It doesn't fix the general API problem, but would resolve this one case.)

Comment: I looked at the neural dependency parser early on, but the parsing was much slower than the lexicalized parser, so I abandoned it before even getting to the punctuation question.  Yes, I did try the = syntax, and it barfed. ;-)  I also tried various other unicode space characters to no avail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128957/discussion-between-dbl-and-alexis).